# Is it possible to create synthesized or modify existing .ONI files in OpenNI 2.x?

Tags: kinect, openni, kinect-sdk, openkinect, simple-openni

Is it possible to create synthesized or modify existing .oni files in OpenNI 2.x? I know it was possible in 1.x using MockDepthGenerator (based NiRecordSynthetic sample), but it looks like this functionality is no longer available in 2.0. Basically, I am trying to convert some Kinect .xed recordings to .oni format while modifying the depth images.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this article can help? http://tayyabnaseer.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/creating-openni-oni-files-from.html

Not sure whether it's just for OpenNI2 or 1